# how to count filled edit text from multiple edittext

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

In my app have twenty edit text,but I want to count filled edit text and that data goes in anther activity through an array. Like when I filled 3 edit text from twenty, that 3 edit text data goes next page and that 3 count goes to next page as an int.

**this is my 1st java class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);

    mspin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.li);
    edt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
    sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc1);

    int no = 20;
    allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    for (int i=1;i<=no;i++){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        edtAdd = new EditText(SelectActivity.this);

        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        allEds.add(edtAdd);
        edtAdd.setHint("Enter Name" + i);
        edtAdd.setId(i);
        layout.addView(edtAdd);
    }
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (allEds.size()<=9) {
                Intent data = new Intent(SelectActivity.this, HalfPieChartActivity.class);
                String[] items = new String[allEds.size()];
                String str = String.valueOf(allEds.size());
                data.putExtra("size", str);  //you don't need to keep this in loop as its same.
                data.putExtra("edt", edt.getText().toString());
                for (int j = 0; j < allEds.size(); j++) {
                    items[j] = allEds.get(j).getText().toString();
                    data.putExtra("edData" + j, items[j]);
                }

                startActivity(data);
            }
            else {
                Intent data = new Intent(SelectActivity.this, FullPieChartActivity.class);
                String[] items = new String[allEds.size()];
                String str = String.valueOf(allEds.size());
                data.putExtra("size", str);// this is the line where I sent that count
                data.putExtra("edt", edt.getText().toString());
                for (int j = 0; j < allEds.size(); j++) {
                    items[j] = allEds.get(j).getText().toString();
                    data.putExtra("edData" + j, items[j]);//here is filled data send line
                }

                startActivity(data);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

When I click submit 20 show in next page as an int.I want to sent that 3data and 3 as an int.
Please help me

Comment: At onclick listener of submit button you should retrieve text from all of your edittext and if it's empty(" ") then it's not filled and if their is any other text then it's filled so, increment your counter. I know it's a redundant code but you can make it simple by making simple function.

Comment: how do i count that filled edit text and get data only from those?

Comment: No you can't get data only from filled edittext. You should get data from all of your 20 edittexts and if user doesn't fiil any data in edittext then edittext.getText() will return empty string and if user filled edittext then you will get data filled by user. so, you can simply count no. of data having non empty strings and that's the count of your filled edittext.

Comment: thats right...how do I count filled edit text?please give me some sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have asked for sample in comment, i am posting my answer with sample.
In onclicklistener of your submit button you can add following code.

```
myNoneEmptyEdittextCounter = 0;
for (int i=1;i<=no;i++)
{
    myEt = (EditText) findViewById(i);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(myEt.getText().toString()))
    {
        myNoneEmptyEdittextCounter +=1;
    }
}
//myNoneEmptyEdittextCounter is count of your filled edittexts
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will return list of data and its size will give you the int you are looking for which is number of filled items.

In submit button click

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(edittextValues().isEmpty()) {
             //nothing has been filled
        } else {
             //items in edittextValues() are your data.
             edittextValues().size();//this is your int which is number of edit text filled.
        }

    }
}
```

I have mentioned in comments what each step does. Hope this helps.

Method **edittextValues()**

```
ArrayList<String> edittextValues() {

    ArrayList<String> filledData = new ArrayList<>(); //initialise empty string array.        

    for (int i=1; i<=20; i++){ //loop through ids from 1 to 20

        for (int j = 0; j< layout.getChildCount(); j++) { //loop through all the children of root layout

            if(layout.getChildAt(j) instanceof EditText) { //filter EditText

                EditText editText = (EditText) layout.getChildAt(j); 

                if(editText.getId() == i) { // filter the one which u programmatically added
                    if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { // check if its not empty, that's the one you are looking
                        filledData.add(editText.getText().toString()); //add it to the list
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return filledData; //return string list
}
```

Comment: So you can identify those edit texts with their ids..which is there in the code on if statement comparing the id == i